# Getting locations from someone elses google maps api key

Tags: google-maps

So I am interested in getting all of the locations of another website that uses google maps to store all of the store locations. I am able to go into the source code and view the api key, probably encrypted but I am not sure.

Is it possible to retrieve all of these locations somehow for personal use?

Not sure if this is explained correctly, will try better if not understood.

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google maps no longer requires an API key and Google does not store location data.  All the maps API does is place locations on a map.  The website stores the location data and passes it to the API, which then geocodes (or reverse geocodes) the location and plots it on a map.

If you have access to the source code, you need to locate where the website stores the locations and then you can geocode it yourself. The Google Maps API is free for personal use and/or any public facing website.

[Google Maps API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/)